# Connecting node to a cluster in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I have created a bucket in my local system and I am trying to connect another node which is located in a remote server. I am able to work with the nodes separately. But I need to join these two nodes to form a cluster. Is there a way to add the remote server node into my local server by using the web UI?

When I tried to add the remote server's IP address by clicking "Add Server", I am getting the following error.
"Attention - Prepare join failed. Authentication failed. Verify username and password. Got HTTP status 401 from REST call post to http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8091/engageCluster2. Body was: []"

I used my local server's username and password. If I give that server's username and password, I get this error.

Attention - This node cannot add another node ('ns_1@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX') because of cluster version compatibility mismatch. Cluster works in [4, 1] mode and node only supports [2, 0].

Is there a way to link them using Java API? Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Are you trying to put a 4.1 and 2.0 node in the same cluster?

Comment: @Laurent Can you please explain? How should I find what type of nodes I am trying to add? 4.1 and 2.0 are different versions of the nodes?

Comment: Are you connecting them to be part of the same cluster (bad idea) or connecting them via XDCR? I ask as connecting remote nodes in the same cluster is usually a bad idea seeing how Couchbase distributes the data across the nodes of the cluster evenly.